# Global Styles Have the Wrong MIME Type When Exporting SSG

Tags: next.js, mime-types

I used `next export` to generate static HTML files. None of the CSS files from `_next/static/css` are being loaded.

Error Message

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/_next/static/css/11068a86edb774164743.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
main-c7eb5c9aa267ed608eb4.js:1
```

The error occurs for the CSS file with global styles and the CSS file with module files.

The site is being deployed to GitHub Pages during development and eventually to a shared hosting service.

Comment: Can you check if the CSS files at that location aren't empty? Do you have any extra webpack config around CSS files?

Comment: The files are not empty. I’m using the gh-pages example from Vercel

Comment: The CSS files are not empty in VS Code, but when I go to the link in the error message it says "Nothing to review"